# C1 Print Preview Dialog disable some save to file options

Tags: c#, winforms, print-preview

I am using `C1PrintPreviewDialog`

Is it possible to disable some of the save to file options – for example `xls` and `xlsx` exports are not working for me so I would like to hide them from end user until problem is resolved.

Thanks

Comment: Too obscure, use the component vendor's support channels.

Comment: Thx, I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone would be interested I have found a solution:

```
C1.Win.C1Preview.C1PrintPreviewDialog c1ppd = new C1.Win.C1Preview.C1PrintPreviewDialog();
c1ppd.PreviewPane.ExportOptions[C1.C1Preview.Export.ExportProviders.XlsExportProvider.FormatKey].Enabled = false;
```